# Is there any way to import all the required Angular Material Classes?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am working on an Angular 2 project. Using Angular Material for designing purposes. Everytime I use a form module. I need to search for the classes that are required for that particular Module.

I just want to know if there is any way to import all the required classes for Angular material.

I am using angular cli for generation and packaging.
Using VS Code as IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
```

This module will import all angular material modules at instant, but you can use this until beta 10 only angular material team will deprecate this in beta 11.

> Reminder that `MaterialModule` is deprecated and will be removed in a
>   subsequent release (see changelog from beta.3 for more information).

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

> MaterialModule
>
> MaterialModule (and MaterialRootModule) have been marked as
>   deprecated. We've found that, with the current state of tree-shaking
>   in the world, that using an aggregate NgModule like MaterialModule
>   leads to tools not being able to eliminate code for components that
>   aren't used.
>
> In order to ensure that users end up with the smallest code size
>   possible, we're deprecating MaterialModule, to be removed in the a
>   subsequent release.
>
> To replace MaterialModule, users can create their own "Material"
>   module within their application (e.g., GmailMaterialModule) that
>   imports only the set of components actually used in the application.

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3991

You can use this when beta 11 is up

```
import {
  MdAutocompleteModule,
  MdButtonModule,
  MdButtonToggleModule,
  MdCardModule,
  MdCheckboxModule,
  MdChipsModule,
  MdDatepickerModule,
  MdDialogModule,
  MdExpansionModule,
  MdFormFieldModule,
  MdGridListModule,
  MdIconModule,
  MdInputModule,
  MdListModule,
  MdMenuModule,
  MdNativeDateModule,
  MdPaginatorModule,
  MdProgressBarModule,
  MdProgressSpinnerModule,
  MdRadioModule,
  MdRippleModule,
  MdSelectModule,
  MdSidenavModule,
  MdSliderModule,
  MdSlideToggleModule,
  MdSnackBarModule,
  MdSortModule,
  MdTableModule,
  MdTabsModule,
  MdToolbarModule,
  MdTooltipModule,
  StyleModule,
 } from '@angular/material';
import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk/table';
import { A11yModule } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import { BidiModule } from '@angular/cdk/bidi';
import { OverlayModule } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
import { PlatformModule } from '@angular/cdk/platform';
import { ObserversModule } from '@angular/cdk/observers';
import { PortalModule } from '@angular/cdk/portal';
```

Comment: Thats what i am doing currently, creating another ngModule import all required classes in it and then import that module to my app module. Even in that case i have to search the documentations for each material module to be used. It seems that's the only solution right now. Thanks!